# How to reshape a dataframe from wide to long for multiple columns on with id field that is non unique in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, reshape

I have a dataframe in a wide format but df1:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[110813,110813,110813,110813],
                   'DATE1':['2019-09-19','2020-05-20',np.nan,np.nan],
                   'DATE2':[np.nan,'2020-06-15',np.nan,'2019-10-24'],
                   'DATE3':[np.nan,'2020-07-20','2020-08-30',np.nan]})
```

resulting in the dataframe below.

| ID | DATE1 | DATE2 | DATE3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 110813 | 2019-09-19 | NaN | NaN |
| 110813 | 2020-05-20 | 2020-06-15 | 2020-07-20 |
| 110813 | NaN | NaN | 2020-08-30 |
| 110813 | NaN | 2019-10-24 | NaN |

The `ID` columns is non-unique because it is a client_id. I want to merge the merge the `DATE1, DATE2, DATE3` columns into `DATE` column so that each `ID` has the history of dates in one field `DATES` as shown below:

| ID | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 110813 | 2019-09-19 |
| 110813 | 2019-10-24 |
| 110813 | 2020-05-20 |
| 110813 | 2020-06-15 |
| 110813 | 2020-07-20 |
| 110813 | 2020-08-30 |

I have tried

```
(pd.wide_to_long(df1,
                           stubnames='DATE',
                           i=['ID'],
                           j='DATES'))
```

but to no avail. Should there be a combination of `df1.unstack()` then `pd.wide_to_long`?

Comment: Just fyi `pandas.np module is deprecated` should be `np.NaN` not `pd.np.NaN` moving forward.

Comment: Please clarify the question. You talk about printing format of a dataframe but also want to remove 2 date columns?

Comment: see edited description of question. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: what is the logic for merging the dates?

Comment: Each date column is represents the first, then 2nd, then 3rd appointment and that is considered 1 cycle. I just want to get that in one column so I have all historic cycles for merging into another dataset

Answer (score 2):

Let's use [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) ([`Series.droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.droplevel.html) to get rid of the old date column names and [`Series.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) to both rename the column and to return it to a DataFrame):

```
out_df = (
    df1.set_index('ID')
        .stack()
        .droplevel(1)
        .reset_index(name='DATE')
)
```

```
       ID        DATE
0  110813  2019-09-19
1  110813  2020-05-20
2  110813  2020-06-15
3  110813  2020-07-20
4  110813  2020-08-30
5  110813  2019-10-24
```

- `stack` is preferred over `melt` because NaN values are automatically dropped.
- `stack` and `melt` are preferred over `wide_to_long` since the id variable (`i`) is non-unique

We can add a [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) if needing in the shown order:

```
out_df = (
    df1.set_index('ID')
        .stack()
        .droplevel(1)
        .reset_index(name='DATE')
        # .astype({'DATE': 'datetime64[ns]'})  # Convert to DateTime
        .sort_values(['ID', 'DATE'], ignore_index=True)
)
```

`out_df`:

```
       ID        DATE
0  110813  2019-09-19
1  110813  2019-10-24
2  110813  2020-05-20
3  110813  2020-06-15
4  110813  2020-07-20
5  110813  2020-08-30
```

Comment: If I was to include the NaNs, how  one achieve that?

Comment: @Mazil_tov998 `.stack(dropna=False)` or `melt`

Comment: As anky says, but your shown output seems to specifically exclude NaN which is why I went with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution** with melt:

```
df1.melt(id_vars=["ID"], 
        var_name='drop_it', 
        value_name="DATE").drop('drop_it', axis=1).dropna().sort_values('DATE')
```

**Result:** (without nans sorted by date)

[image]